# Blur TextView on click, Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to blur out a `TextView`, when a button is clicked. So far my code looks likes this:

```java
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        float radius = pdf.getTextSize() / 3;
        BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
        if (v==pause){
            if (paused){
                paused=false;
                pdf.getPaint().setMaskFilter(null);
            }
            else{
                paused=true;
                pdf.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: AppCompatTextView not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer (or drawing cache), needs 17854560 bytes, only 8294400 available.

Answer (score 0):

just set  this

```
 pdf.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

befor line: pdf.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);

Comment: That dose not work, all the text just disappear when  do that

Comment: please add all of your codes. for example i dont know what is pdf . and its better to add your layout